# Active high and active low in IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, alu

I am using an alu SN74ls181 . I am  unable to figure out how active high and active low are decided . Is it during the manufacturing or some circuit parameters decide if the circuit is active high or low.

Comment: Whoever designs the chip makes that decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chip does not care, it reacts to voltage levels, not to logic signals.

This chip has two tables that describe the logic function it implements. The first one shows the functions when YOU define low = 1, high = 0:

[image]

The second table describes the same logical circuits, but now using the (common) convention high = 1, low = 0:

[image]

To illustrate the point, look at the last-but-one row, second column. In the first table (active low logic) it states F = AB, which is the math notation for the AND function. In the second table the same entry states F = A + B, which is the logical (inclusive) OR function. This all makes perfect sense: the common OR port IS AN AND PORT FOR 0's.

Comment: Why do the arithmatic operations do not match? Like for LLLH with no carry there is extra minus 1 in active low data.

Comment: That has to do with the definition of 2's complement: to get - N you invert all the bits of N *and then you add 1*.

Answer (score 1):

It's because when using the active low convention, the 1's are treated the same as 0's are in active high convention. 
For example, having A = 1111 and B = 1011 and HHHL as selection:
 - In active high, F equals A | B. In this case, F = 1111.
 - In active low, A would be seen as 0000, B as 0100 and F as 0000; which is equivalent to F = AB